# php date with “h” instead of “:”

Tags: php, datetime, time

Other posts didnt solve my issue, is not a repeated question.

```
            if($userinfo2['tmZone']!="null")
            {
                $timezone  = $userinfo2['tmZone']; //Time zone from database
                echo "Local time : " . gmdate("H:i", time() + 3600*($timezone+date("I")));
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Local time : No data";
            }
```

**I would like to print the hour and minutes with "h" as separator and not ":"**

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just escape the "h" :

```
$time = gmdate("H\hi", time() + 3600*($timezone+date("I")));
```

Output :

> 23h07

Comment: Perfect. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

How about this? `echo gmdate("H\h i\m\i\\n", time());`